# Why is my out_of_range exception not being caught

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling

I am new to cpp and I am trying out several things. This one I can't seem to figure out on my own.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class E, class V> 
struct Pair {
    E first;
    V second;

    Pair(E fst, V snd) : first(fst), second(snd) {}

    E getFirst() { return first; }
    V getSecond() { return second; }
};

template <class t, unsigned dim> 
struct vec {
    t d[dim];

    static constexpr int dimen = dim;

    t &operator[](unsigned n) {
        std::printf("dim: %d %d\n", dim, n);
        if (n >= dim) {
            std::printf("checking %d\n", n);
            throw std::out_of_range("vector index is out of range");
        }
        return d[n];
   };
};

int main() {

    try {
        Pair<int, vec<int, 2> *> test2(2, new vec<int, 2>{1, 2});
        std::printf("%d\n", test2.getSecond()->dimen);
        std::printf("before\n");
        std::printf("%d\n", test2.getSecond()->d[2]); // it seems like the compiler kind of ignores this
    } catch (std::out_of_range e) {
        std::printf("Caught!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the line `std::printf("%d\n", test2.getSecond()->d[2]);` should ideally throw the out_of_range error, but it is not. My linter actually warns me that this is out of range also. I can compile and run the program and it returns some garbage `0` value.

My question is: why is *either* the error not being thrown or the error not being caught? I think the error is not being thrown because *checking* is not printed when I run it.

Comment: Bounds checking is only done with the `.at()` method, not with the indexing operator `[]`.

Comment: `->d[2]` this indexes the `d` member, which is a good old C style array.

Comment: This is described in the documentation for these methods. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: Note: in general you should catch exceptions by `const` reference `&` in most  cases, not by value. So `catch (const std::out_of_range& e)`. Won't fix this problem, just a piece of advice on best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the reference on that Jesper, I'll definitely do that from now on. To the answers above, in my `operator` method, I check if the index `n` is greater than or equal to `dim`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: `test2.getSecond()->d[2]` should be `(*test2.getSecond())[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `throw` code is never actually reached.

In this line here:

```
std::printf("%d\n", test2.getSecond()->d[2]);
```

`getSection()` returns a pointer to the `vec` object. When you then do `->d` you are accessing the `d` array, within the `vec` object. Thus, when you add the `[2]` to the end, you are accessing the element at index 2 of the array, and are not calling `operator[]` of the `vec` object.

If you rewrite like this:

```
std::printf("%d\n", (*test2.getSecond())[2]);
```

Then the `operator[]` will be called on the `vec` object, and not its array. Note that you have to dereference the result of `getSecond()`. Alternatively, you can be more verbose:

```
std::printf("%d\n", test2.getSecond()->operator[](2));
```

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/YWKzPz

Answer (score 1):

Very good question!

The issue is that when you try to reference an item in an array via index, such as [2], you are actually referring to the size * 2 location. There is no built-in protection against it, but you can always check for \0 as that's where your arrays end. When you use arrays in C/C++, it is your job to make sure you are not outside of their location. It's generally a good idea to keep your array inside your structure/class and allow reaching its elements with setters and getters, which would handle the bounds and throw exceptions if those are violated.